# Bash pattern to match directories whose names begin with a dot (period), by being "explicit", instead of using "shopt -s dotglob"?

Tags: bash, shell, wildcards, dot-files, bash-expansion

When constructing a pattern that matches a file name such as `/home/user/project/.git`, how does one match the `.` character "explicitly" -- that is, without the use of `shopt -s dotglob`?

The manual at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html states:

> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘.’ at the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set.

What, exactly, does it mean, to "be matched explicitly"?

And again, at http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html (in the `Notes` section at the end), the same notion is addressed:

> Filename expansion can match dotfiles, but only if the pattern explicitly includes the dot as a literal character.

The note provides the following examples:

```
~/[.]bashrc    #  Will not expand to ~/.bashrc
~/?bashrc      #  Neither will this.
               #  Wild cards and metacharacters will NOT
               #+ expand to a dot in globbing.

~/.[b]ashrc    #  Will expand to ~/.bashrc
~/.ba?hrc      #  Likewise.
~/.bashr*      #  Likewise.
```

I fail to understand the inner workings of the last three examples, which will expand to include the "dotfile".

How, specifically, does placing the `b` in brackets after the `.` make this an "explicit" match in the example `~/.[b]ashrc`? The subsequent examples are even more ambiguous to me. I simply fail to understand how manipulating the pattern in ways that seem completely unrelated to the `.` character cause the pattern to produce a match.

With regard to why I would like to avoid using `shopt -s dotglob`, the impetus for this question is rooted in the fact that I am writing these patterns for use in another program's configuration file. I want to exclude paths that contain, for example, "hidden `.git` directories", and I'm not sure that I have the ability to specify `dotglob` in any capacity.

In essence: What is the simplest means by which to match the `.` character by "being explicit"? Placing the next character in brackets "makes it work", but I'd like to know why; I feel like I'm "shooting in the dark" with that approach.

Any explanation as to the underlying behavior in this regard is much appreciated.

EDIT TO ADD:

Initially, it didn't seem relevant, but because people seem to be interested in the specifics of my use-case, I'll explain further.

I'm using a Host-Based Intrusion Detection software called `Samhain`. Samhain will "alert" whenever the filesystem is modified according to certain user-specified configuration parameters.

I *don't* want Samhain to alert when files within `.git` directories (that are located within certain parent directories) are created/modified/deleted. In Samhain, this type of exclusion is performed by defining "ignore rules". The exact specification of these rules is explained at http://www.la-samhna.de/samhain/manual/filedef.html , in `4.2. File/directory specification`.

In short:

> `Wildcard patterns ('*', '?', '[...]') as in shell globbing are supported for paths. The leading '/' is mandatory.`

So, I am trying to write an "ignore rule" that will match the `.git` directories in question, which will, in effect, cause Samhain to exclude them from its monitoring activities.

Initially, I tried this:

```
[IgnoreAll]
dir = -1/home/user/project/*/*/.git
```

This didn't work; Samhain still alerted whenever files inside those `.git` directories changed.

Upon finding the examples cited above, I tried this:

```
dir = -1/home/user/project/*/*/.[g]it
```

With this change, Samhain ignores the files, as desired.

In posting this question, I was simply trying to understand why that change has the intended effect.

I will say, I feel less stupid given that the very pattern I was trying to use at first does indeed match the `.git` directories in question when I use "echo" test:

```
echo /home/user/project/*/*/.git
```

So, it wasn't so much that I was misunderstanding something fundamental with regard to pattern-matching, globbing, or file-name expansion in Bash; to the contrary, there seem to be nuances with regard to how Samhain, in particular, implements pattern-matching in this context.

I have no idea why this doesn't work when applied in the context of Samhain's configuration file (obviously). Maybe somebody will be able to explain, given this edit.

Comment: I read your question and I really don't get your confusion, **especially** since you don't want to include the hidden (dot) files.  The examples you don't understand are simply showing that the file name needs to start with the `.` to be found, whatever the rest if it matches.

Comment: @JuliePelletier Perhaps the edit I just made will clarify.

Comment: The reasons people questioned your question are (1) You spent most of the question saying “Explain the manual to me.”  (2) You said, “I want to exclude paths that …”, which is not the same as “I want to exclude [these] paths *by specifying a pattern that matches them in an `Ignore` directive.*” See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I assume that you know
what things like `[b]`, `?` and `*` mean in a pathname pattern. 
(If you don’t, do more research.)

At the risk of repeating what the others have said,
you’re overthinking it. 
Patterns that contain the string `/.`
(i.e., a `/` *immediately* followed by a **`.`**)
explicitly include the dot as a literal character. 
The point is just that `[b]`, `?` and/or `*` occurring *after* the **`.`**
don’t affect whether the pattern can match dotfile(s). 
The last three examples are offered as examples of *patterns*
(i.e., not just a plain file/pathname,
but something that could potentially match several file/pathnames – or none)
that will match `~/.bashrc` — as opposed to the first two,
which *would* match `~/.bashrc` if **`.`** weren’t handled specially.

So, what is your real question?

> … I am writing these patterns
>   for use in another program’s configuration file. 
>   I want to exclude paths that contain, for example,
>   “hidden `.git` directories”, and I’m not sure
>   that I have the ability to specify `dotglob` in any capacity.

I guess you want to do something (like `chown` or `cp`)
to all files/directories *except* those beginning with dot. 
But your code is going to be used in somebody else’s script
(via the **`.`** or `source` command),
and you’re afraid to do `your_command *`
because the script may have set `dotglob`,
so `*` would expand to all files, including “hidden” ones. 
And you don’t want to turn off `dotglob`
because you don’t want to break the functionality of the existing script.

1. Use a smarter wildcard (pathname expansion pattern).

   I hope that you understand wildcards (a.k.a. globs) like `[abc]` —
   they match any of the characters `a`, `b` or `c`. 
   For example, the string `c[aou]t` matches `cat`, `cot` and `cut`; 
   `d[iou]g` matches `dig`, `dog` and `dug`. 
   (They can be, and commonly are, used with ranges;
   e.g., `[a-z]` and `[0-9]`.) 
   Well, a special case of this is `[!abc]` —
   it matches any character ***except*** `a`, `b` or `c`. 
   So you can use `[!.]*` (or `directory_name/[!.]*`)
   to match names that begin with a character other than dot. 
   Paradoxically, `[.]` (at the beginning of a filename)
   won’t match a dot if `dotglob` is not set,
   but `[!.]` will *exclude* a dot regardless of the setting of `dotglob`.

   This will give the same result whether `dotglob` is set or not.
2. Use `dotglob` (in a subshell).

   Shell options (`shopt`s) are local to a process,
   and process attributes never flow backwards (uphill) from child to parent. 
   So

   ```
   (shopt -u dotglob; your_command *)
   ```

   will run *`your_command`* on non-hidden files only,
   without affecting the settings and behavior of the rest of the script.
3. Use `dotglob` (without using a subshell).

   Some people prefer to avoid subshells because they use extra resources. 
   But the cost is minuscule
   (unless you do it in a loop that executes *many* times),
   so this is not a very good reason. 
   A better reason to avoid a subshell is
   if you need to do something that affects the environment of the shell,
   like `cd` or `umask`.

   If this is your situation, you can temporarily turn off `dotglob`,
   and later restore the previous setting.

   If you type `shopt dotglob` (without `-s` or `-u`),
   it reports (displays) the current setting of the `dotglob` option. 
   (`shopt` with *no* parameters
   lists the current settings of *all* the options.) 
   It also sets the exit status accordingly. 
   The `-q` flag suppresses the display, so you can do

   ```
   shopt -q dotglob
   dotglob_setting=$?
   shopt -u dotglob
   your_command *
   if [ "$dotglob_setting" = 0 ]
   then
       shopt -s dotglob
   fi
   ```

---

**But wait …** you said “another program’s configuration file”. 
What are you talking about? 
If you’re talking about
writing or modifying a file that says something like `ignore=*.o`,
then this whole question doesn’t make sense,
because that file will be processed (and interpreted)
by whatever program processes it,
and ***that program*** will decide how to interpret `*` —
the shell has nothing to do with it.

---

OK, now that we have a better idea of what the question is:

The short answer is that
the behavior that you’re seeing doesn’t make sense. 
If a `.git` directory exists,
then specifying it exactly (literally) as `.git`
and specifying it with a wildcard / glob pattern of `.[g]it`
should behave identically.

The longer answer:
I stand by the last paragraph of the first version of my answer. 
Samhain is reading and parsing its policy configuration file. 
It might use the shell to interpret wildcards in the config file,
but I guess that it’s doing it internally.

And, if it is “using the shell”, which shell is it using? 
On many systems, `/bin/sh` is not bash. 
Their baseline behavior with regards to pathname expansion patterns
(i.e., wildcards) should be the same,
but once you step off the porch, you’re in a swamp. 
The POSIX specification for the shell doesn’t even have the `shopt` command,
and (AFAIK) doesn’t have any way to make `*` expand to *all* files
(and not just non-hidden ones).

If you feel like <del>wasting</del> spending some more time on this,
you might experiment with
putting  `/home/user/project/*` into the Samhain config file
and seeing whether it interprets it as all files or just non-hidden ones. 
If it interprets it as all files, we can conclude

1. Samhain isn’t using `/bin/sh` to expand wildcards.
2. It isn’t using standard, default rules for wildcards
   (the ones you discussed at such length in your question).
3. The documentation is wrong (or, at best, incomplete and misleading)
   inasmuch as it says, “Wildcard patterns (‘*’, ‘?’, ‘[...]’)
   as in shell globbing are supported for paths.” without saying that
   (unlike in the shell’s default behavior) `*` means all files.
4. It *might* be using bash in `dotglob` mode to expand wildcards. 
   But this doesn’t make sense;
   as I said, the handling of `.git` and `.[g]it`
   doesn’t correspond to the normal behavior of any shell that I know of. 
   It’s almost certainly got its own code for wildcards.

But in any case I believe that we can say with some confidence
that your conclusion is correct: Samhain has a bug
with regard to the handling of wildcards in `IgnoreAll` specifications. 
You might want to file a bug report with the vendor. 
Or, since you’ve found a workaround, you could just forget about it.

Comment: You assumption is correct; I understand the meaning of `?`, `*`, `[]`, etc. in this context. And you are likely correct in that my original question is flawed on the premise that the pattern I was trying to use does in fact match the directories in question. My confusion seems to stem from some implementation detail in Samhain (see my recent edit for details) that deviates from what I observe on the shell. I don't know whether to ask a new question, edit this one's title, or something else altogether. Any advice in that regard is appreciated. I'm considering accepting your answer instead, too.

Comment: Thank you, G-Man. I really appreciate your exhaustive analysis and the time you've invested in helping me identify the likely cause of my frustration with this issue. My feeling is that you deserve the Accepted Answer. jayhendren's answer is also good, and it addresses (what I thought was) my original question, but your continued persistence and concrete suggestions for identifying a root-cause go above-and-beyond. Again, thank you. I will update the question if I'm able to determine what, exactly, is causing the observed behavior. There is always a good chance of "operator error"!

Answer (score 7):

> When a pattern is used for filename expansion, the character ‘.’ at
>   the start of a filename or immediately following a slash must be
>   matched explicitly, unless the shell option dotglob is set.

This simply means the globs `*`, `?`, and `[...]` don't match a `.` at the beginning of a filename.  If you want to match a `.` at the beginning of a filename, you can't use a glob, you have to type the `.` explicitly.  For instance:

```
$ echo ????
Work
$ echo .???
.gem .pki .ssh .vim
```

And to answer your other question:

> How, specifically, does placing the `b` in brackets after the `.` make
>   this an "explicit" match in the example `~/.[b]ashrc`?

Just because you're using a glob pattern doesn't mean that the *whole* pattern is no longer "explicit". In `~/.[b]ashrc`, for instance, the characters `/.ashrc` are all explicitly matched. However, `[b]` is a glob pattern and also not an explicit match.  (Technically, `~` is a tilde expansion and performed earlier than glob expansion, so it is an explicit match as well.) But the other characters, including `.`, **do** match explicitly, which is why `~/.[b]ashrc` matches `~/.bashrc`.

For comparison, `~/?[b]ashrc` will **not** match `~/.bashrc`, because the `.` is no longer matched explicitly.

Comment: Tilde expansion occurs much earlier, so by the time pathname expansion occurs, `~/.bash*` would be seen as `/home/bob/.bash*` (i.e., unquoted tildes are long gone by the time the pattern matcher gets involved).

Comment: @jayhendren Thank you for your time and assistance here. If you've kept up with the edits and follow-ups, you know that I'm the schmuck here and I posted a "bad question". Your answer was helpful and succinct, given my original question, but I think G-Man deserves the Accepted Answer, given the extent to which he has provided useful follow-up information after I edited the question to explain the specific use-case.